# Converting from decimal to hex

Tags: encoding, hex, go

I want to convert a number to hex and store the result in a `[]byte` up to length 4.
Here's what I came up with, but it feels very roundabout.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    hexstring := fmt.Sprintf("%x", 12345678)
    fmt.Println(hexstring)
    hexbytes, _ := hex.DecodeString(hexstring)
    for {
        if len(hexbytes) >= 4 {
            break
        }
        hexbytes = append(hexbytes, 0)
    }
    fmt.Println(hexbytes)
}
```

I think there must be a better way to do this using `make([]byte, 4)` and the `encoding/binary` package, but I couldn't get it to work.

Sandbox link: http://play.golang.org/p/IDXCatYQXY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood your question, it isn't really about hex at all. You want to take a 32-bit integer, treat it as 4 bytes, and put those bytes into a `[]byte`.

For this, you want the `ByteOrder` type (actually, its subtypes `LittleEndian` and `BigEndian`) from the `encoding/binary` package. Something like this:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"encoding/binary"
)

func main() {

    x := 12345678
    b := [4]byte{}
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(b[:], uint32(x))
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

Comment: Ah, This is really close but check out the difference.. http://play.golang.org/ .. I admit, I may be wrong as to how I'm expressing what I want but it needs to be in the order / endedness of the first example I'm afraid...

Comment: If you want big-endian rather than little-endian, all you need to do is to replace `LittleEndian` with `BigEndian` in the code above. I don't believe you can possibly want the exact endedness the first example gives, because it gives the same results for (e.g.) 0xFF, 0xFF00, 0xFF0000, and 0xFF000000. (It also gives an array full of zeros for, e.g., 1, 0x100, 0x10000, and 0x1000000.)

Comment: If you mean that ff 00 00 00 would be correct when the actual number is 255, then I'm pretty sure what you want is exactly the code I gave above. The code you posted is neither big-endian nor little-endian, and I am really very sure that it can't be what your file format calls for. (Did you try feeding it the values I mentioned and looking at the output?) But maybe I've misunderstood something. Could you give an example where your code and mine give different results, and explain why yours is right and mine is wrong?

Comment: By the way, do you see why I say that this isn't really about hex? What the file header contains is four *bytes*. You could write them as 255 0 0 0 instead of FF 00 00 00 and it would still be the same four bytes.

Comment: Storing in little-endian form and padding with trailing zeros is exactly equivalent to just storing 4 bytes little-endian, which is what my code does. Storing in big-endian form and padding with trailing zeros (which is roughly what your code does) produces ambiguous results of the sort I described above. Could you give an example where you believe that both the big-endian and the little-endian versions of my code produce wrong results, and say what you think the right result is and why? Thanks.

Comment: No trouble. Glad to be of service.